# Objective C ARC release without assigning a variable

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

In Objective C ARC, is it safe to do [[[MYObject alloc] init] callingSomeMethod]? Will it get released even if I dont assign to a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will. If you're nervous about it, it's easy to verify. Just put NSLog(@"it did!"); in that object's -dealloc method and check to make sure it logs.

Answer (score 0):

**If** you don't need the object to live after `callingSomeMethod` returns, it is safe to do `[[[MyObject alloc] init] callingSomeMethod]`.

If you need the object to live after `callingSomeMethod` returns, then your program needs to create a strong reference to it before `callingSomeMethod` returns.  Examples:

- If `callingSomeMethod` sets the object as the target of an `NSTimer`, you are safe because `NSTimer` retains its target.
- If `callingSomeMethod` only sets the object as the delegate of a `UITableView`, you are *not* safe, because `UITableView` does *not* retain its delegate.  In that case, you must also create a strong reference to the object somewhere else.